# is this a form of denial?

Tags: questions

Is it called denial if I see and notice my dog but don't pay attention to it? 
If it is can you give me a description of denial in that form, me and my brother are in a debate about it, I say it is and he says it isn't.

Comment: Did you look up *deny* and *denial*? Do you have dictionary support? You can indeed "deny" your dog, but your brother can deny your argument by referring to a different definition (the closer to the top, the more common the meaning.)

Comment: I think it's perfectly reasonable to say something along the lines of: "I am denying my dog attention." This has the connotation that the dog desires attention from you and you are deliberately choosing to not give it any.

Comment: It can be called *denial of affection*, but not plain *denial*.

Answer (score 3):

Would that not be simply be ***[ignoring](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ignore)*** the dog? Not able to come up with a word can be maddening indeed; hope this helps.

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ignore